# Launching apps before user log in with GNOME

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

Is it technically possible to launch a desktop app on Gnome (Fedora or any other RHEL based distro) without being forced to log in first into the user session?

I need to boot a desktop software on system start even if there is no user to log in at that moment. Setting the account to automatically log in is of course an option but highly insecure to leave a system in that state.

Comment: A graphical app can't really run at that point  because there's no X server or (wayland compositor) for it to connect to. It sounds like you maybe actually want to write a system service (daemon) and a separate user app that connects to the system service.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to run the software in the session that runs GDM. However, I'd suggest considering some alternatives.

What about running a VNC session (Fedora includes `tigervnc`), and running the app inside that? You could set up some dummy user account to do this, and have this happen automatically through either a systemd unit or maybe an `@reboot` crontab entry.

Comment: I think I might up doing that, as I don't think its possible to run something without starting a user session first. Creating a dummy session seems to be the only option.

Comment: Ultimately, I think it probably _is_ possible but it's definitely outside of design scope and really really generally a bad idea.

Comment: Actually I don't think its possible as I found another post here on StackOverflow that explains there is no GDM up to the moment the user logs in and this is per user. Only when the session is started the graphical interface is also generated on the fly. No login (no session), means there is GUI to run the application.

Comment: It would be possible -- the login screen is a mini session. It runs some things like international input support. You might have to modify the code slightly to get it to do what you want. But it's _really_ not a good idea.